# Can't hide button without breaking script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to hide all text and display a overlay on a button click, while then being able to add the text back and remove the overlay when clicking anywhere on the screen.

For some reason it works with h1 and p elements, but when adding the button element it breaks.

This works:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h1 class="contact-title">Portland Based</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <button type="button" href="#" class="btn btn-outline-warning letsTalk hidden-xs-down" id="contact">Let's talk</button>
      <p>this works too</p>
      <button type="button" href="#" class="btn btn-warning letsTalk hidden-sm-up">Let's talk</button>
    </div>
  </div>

#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 10000;
    display: block;
}


$("#contact").on('click', function (e) {
  if (!$('#overlay').length) {
    $('body').append('<div id="overlay"> </div>');
    $('h1').hide();
    $('p').hide();
  }
}).keyup(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 27) {
    $('#overlay').remove();
    $('h1').show();
    $('p').show();
  }
}).blur(function (e) {
  $('#overlay').remove();
  $('h1').show();
  $('p').show();
});
$('body').click(function (e) {
  if (!$(e.target).is('#contact')) {
    $('#overlay').remove();
    $('h1').show();
    $('p').show();
  }
})
```

This doesn't:

```
$("#contact").on('click', function (e) {
  if (!$('#overlay').length) {
    $('body').append('<div id="overlay"> </div>');
    $('h1').hide();
    $('p').hide();
    $('button').hide();
  }
}).keyup(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 27) {
    $('#overlay').remove();
    $('h1').show();
    $('p').show();
    $('button').show();
  }
}).blur(function (e) {
  $('#overlay').remove();
  $('h1').show();
  $('p').show();
  $('button').show();
});
$('body').click(function (e) {
  if (!$(e.target).is('#contact')) {
    $('#overlay').remove();
    $('h1').show();
    $('p').show();
    $('button').show();
  }
})
```

Any help would be great! Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZWNjW)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$("#contact").on('click blur keyup', function (e) {
  if ($('#overlay').length == 0) {
    $('body').append('<div id="overlay"> </div>');
    $('h1').hide();
    $('p').hide();
    $('button').hide();
  }
  if (e.which == 27) {
    $('#overlay').remove();
    $('h1').show();
    $('p').show();
    $('button').show();
  }
});

$('body').click(function (e) {
  if (!$(e.target).is('#contact')) {
    $('#overlay').remove();
    $('h1').show();
    $('p').show();
    $('button').show();
  }
});
```

```css
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 10000;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h1 class="contact-title">Portland Based</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <button type="button" href="#" class="btn btn-outline-warning letsTalk hidden-xs-down" id="contact">Let's talk</button>
      <p>this works too</p>
      <button type="button" href="#" class="btn btn-warning letsTalk hidden-sm-up">Let's talk</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Hope this will be helpful to you :)

Comment: You the real MVP

Comment: You can optimize it by using `$('h1, p, buton').show();`

Comment: @MilanChheda Thank you for the optimization!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to hide all the elements. If my assumption is wrong, let me know!

Here is a quick fix. Instead of "manually" hiding and showing content, I wrap it up in `content` div and toggle the `opacity` accordingly.

```
$("#contact").on('click', function (e) {
      if (!$('#overlay').length) {
        $('body').append('<div id="overlay"> </div>');
        $("#content").css({ opacity: "0" });

      }
    }).keyup(function (e) {
      if (e.which == 27) {
        $('#overlay').remove();
        $('#content').css({ 'opacity': '1' });
      }
    }).blur(function (e) {
      $('#overlay').remove();
      $('#content').css({ 'opacity': '1' });
    });
    $('body').click(function (e) {
      if (!$(e.target).is('#contact')) {
        $('#overlay').remove();
        $('#content').css({ 'opacity': '1' });
      }
    })

$("#contact").on('click', function (e) {
      if (!$('#overlay').length) {
        $('body').append('<div id="overlay"> </div>');
        $("#content").css({ opacity: "0" });

      }
    }).keyup(function (e) {
      if (e.which == 27) {
        $('#overlay').remove();
        $('#content').css({ 'opacity': '1' });
      }
    }).blur(function (e) {
      $('#overlay').remove();
      $('#content').css({ 'opacity': '1' });
    });
    $('body').click(function (e) {
      if (!$(e.target).is('#contact')) {
        $('#overlay').remove();
        $('#content').css({ 'opacity': '0' });
      }
    })
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXMYbB)

Comment: Thank you for the solution! I already chose an answer but I gave you reputation!